# Whether it is possible to get copy of my W-2 from IRS for past few years?

Tags: united-states, irs

Whether it is possible to get copy of my W-2 from IRS for past few years?

For some reasons, i need to have copy of my last 7 years W-2. I was wondering whether it is possible for me to get my copies from IRS ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You, or anyone with your permission, can request a copy of your tax returns including W-2 forms by using [Form 4506](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/f4506.pdf), or you can request just a transcript using [Form 4506-T](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/f4506t.pdf).

[Here's an explanation](https://blog.4506-transcripts.com/2012/08/20/difference-between-the-forms-4506-4506-t-and-4506t-ez/) of the differences.

Or, if you know of all of your employers that issued you a W-2 in the last 7 years, you could try contacting them instead to get another copy.